# Window clicked - what happens then?

Tags: c++, mouse, window, click, hwnd

I am working on a limited remote control of another PC over network. At first the controlled window is chosen and the client may control that window and all child windows. I am having a problem with the mouse though, I can move it using SetCursorPos, but when I try to send the WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages, there is no result. I believe it's necessary for the window to be in the foreground first, but I am uncertain if SetForegroundWindow does exactly what happens after a click before the WM_ message is posted. Do you know how I can send a mouseclick directly to the window (if it's not a child window of a particular HWND, it's not allowed to be clicked).

Comment: Use PostMessage, not SendMessage.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better (and possibly easier) to use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx). I believe that is the recommended way to mimic a user using the mouse, instead of trying to mess with window messages directly.

Comment: That goes to the window with the focus.